# How to clone input text into the other input text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the first input clone into the second input.

```
<label for="text-basic">Harga 1 gram emas murni :   </label>

<input type="text" name="emas" id="emas" value="">

<label for="textinput-1">Nisab :</label>
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="nisab" id="nisab" placeholder="" value="" >
```

Comment: This does not meet the guidelines for posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way would be to use jQuery.

Include the library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textOne" onkeyup="clone();" />
<input type="text" id="textTwo" />
```

Javascript:

```
function clone() {

     $("#textTwo").val($("#textOne").val());

}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5c8a9w39/